# View formatted sqlite results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, command-line-interface

So I code using ruby on rails and the default database is sqlite, which is amazing for development. there is no setup time, no need for connection etc. What really sucks is the output on the command line. when i do a query to list all the contents of a table for example. I just get a dump of text, unlike when you use MySql, the CLI formats the results of the queries nicely (with headers in a table). I am also aware of "headers on" and the commands you can type to format the results of sqlite but those are temporary and I am looking for a more permanent way to format the results so i do not have to do it every-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you can specify SQL statements and metadata statements in an [init file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sqlite3) and pass this file as the `-init` parameter.